# How do I display tags comma separated with "and" between the last two tags?

Tags: templating, tags

I would like to output a tag-list like this:

**foo, bar and baz**

I know how to elegantly output a tag list with no comma after the last tag:

```
{% for tag in tags %}
    {{ tag }}{{ not loop.last ? ', ' }}
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a similarly elegant solution for getting the tags to display the way I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bit of an old question, but here's a (subjectively) more elegant solution than the accepted answer using [`loop.revindex0`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable):

```
{% for tag in tags %}
    {{ tag.type }}{{ loop.revindex0 == 1 ? ' and' : loop.revindex0 ? ', '  }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Might be that `revindex0` didn't exist yet at the time I originally posted my question :)

Answer (score 6):

Not very elegant, but... :)

```
{% for tag in tags %}
    {{ tag.type }}{{ loop.index < loop.length-1 ? ', ' : loop.index < loop.length ? ' and' }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Elegant enough for me! I didn't know I could nest another ternary operation inside the first one. Thank you.

Comment: You could use `loop.revindex` or `loop.revindex0` to test how far you are from the end if you wanted to, for just a bit more elegance/obscurity.

Answer (score 1):

You can output tags as a list (using `<li>` and `<ul>` tags) and add commas and `and` with CSS:

```
li {display:inline}
li:before {content:', ';}
li:first-child:before {content:'';}
li:last-child:before {content:' and ';}
```

This will require that all the spaces between tags be removed so that your template code would look like this:

```
{% for tag in tags %}{{ tag }}{% endfor %}
```