# How do I add commas to an output that returns a list of names?

Tags: templating

I have a simple `for loop` to get the names of countries from a category.

```
{% for name in country %} {{ name.title }} {% endfor %}
```

The output is typically returns the name of 1 country.  But, some entries are associated with more than one country.

For example:

> Belgium Czech Republic Denmark Greece Netherlands Norway Portugal

**How do I template for an entry that returns 2-N country names by adding `","` between each country and `"and"` before the last country?**

This is what I want to output:

> Belgium, Czech Republic, Denmark, Greece, Netherlands, Norway and Portugal

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2377/how-do-i-display-tags-comma-separated-with-and-between-the-last-two-tags

Answer (score 1):

You can use [loop variables](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable)

```
{% set i = country|length %} // number of total items
{% set indexLast = i - 2 %}  // index of the last comma
{% for name in country %}
    {% if loop.last and i > 1 %} and {% endif %}{{ name.title }}{%if i > 2 and loop.index0 < indexLast  %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Explanation:

- if there is more than one item and it is the last iteration: add an `and` at the beginning
- if there are more than 2 items (otherwise it's only one `and`) and the current loop index is smaller than `count - 2` ( it should display nothing in the last iteration and only an `and` before the last)-> display a comma `,`

Comment: `Unexpected token "name" of value "last" ("end of statement block" expected).`.